# PHP increment booking number according to the last booking number in database

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm using PHP 7 with Phalcon PHP and I'm trying to create a method to generate a booking number. Here is my current method :

```
public function generateNumber($company_code) {
    // Build the prefix : COMPANY20190820
    $prefix = $company_code . date('Ymd');

    // It's like SELECT count(*) FROM bookings WHERE number LIKE 'COMPANY20190820%'
    $counter = Bookings::count(array(
        "number LIKE :number:",
        "bind" => array('number' => $prefix.'%')
    )); 

    // Concat prefix with bookings counter with str_pad
    // COMPANY20190820 + 005 (if 4 bookings in DB)
    $booking_number = $prefix . str_pad($counter + 1, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

    // Return COMPANY20190820005
    return $booking_number;
}
```

So I have a problem because sometime I have to delete 1 or multiple bookings so I can get :

```
COMPANY20190820001
COMPANY20190820002
COMPANY20190820005
COMPANY20190820006
COMPANY20190820007
```

And I need to add after the last in my DB so here `007`, because I can get duplicated booking number if I count like that.

So how can I do to take the last and increment according the last booking number of the current day ?

Comment: Race condition apart, I presume you want `SELECT MAX(...) + 1` rather than `SELECT COUNT(*)` (no idea of the Phalcon semantics, sorry). However, I can't understand the overall idea or why you're avoiding the typical database solutions (sequences/auto-incremented numbers or UUIDs). This algorithm seems specially crafted to reuse IDs of deleted bookings—is that your intention?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes when I reply to myself I used max and it works. I don't want to use id or uuid because it will be the reference number of the customer and it should be readable. That is why I display the current date and each reference number of the day is incremented

Comment: I don't see race condition in my answer below

Comment: Unless there's a mechanism to lock data from reading (I don't know), there's a timespan between getting the maximum and inserting the new row in which  two simultaneous bookings can get the same ID.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Ok I see, but if I have an unique index on this field, I'll don't get this problem ?

Comment: That should certainly prevent invalid insertions. It's up to your code to handle it gracefully for the user.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Because I don't have any idea in which format I have to store this booking number, I need a unique easy number because the customer can read it to call the support with this number if he has a problem, that is why I'll not use uuid, I think I just need prefix + number

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález https://myonlinesecurity.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Your-reservation-is-now-confirmed.png if you look this image, booking.com generate only number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rethink what you want to do here as it will never work that way.

As I see it you have at least two options:

1. Use an auto-increment id and use that in combination with the prefix
2. Use a random fairly unique string (e.g. UUID4)

You should never manually try to get the current maximum id as that may and most likely will at some point result in race conditions and brittle code as a result of that.

Comment: UUID isn't readable for the customer. I prefer to use `prefix + only number` it's easier, what solution do you propose?

Comment: As said you still have the first options which is use the sequence generated by the database.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution, maybe there is a better way to do that but my function works now:

```
public function generateNumber($company_code) {
    // Build the prefix : COMPANY20190820
    $prefix = $company_code . date('Ymd');

    // Get the last booking with the today prefix
    // e.g : COMPANY20190820005
    $last_booking = Bookings::maximum(array(
        "column" => "number",
        "number LIKE :number:",
        "bind" => array('number' => $prefix.'%')
    ));

    // Get the last number by removing the prefix (e.g 005)
    $last_number = str_replace($prefix, "", $last_booking);
    // trim left 0 if exist to get only the current number
    // cast to in to increment my counter (e.g 5 + 1 = 6)
    $counter = intval(ltrim($last_number, "0")) + 1;
    // Concat prefix + counter with pad 006
    $booking_number = $prefix . str_pad($counter, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

    // Return COMPANY20190820006
    return $booking_number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon that the use case you describe does not justify the hassle of writing a custom sequence generator in PHP. Additionally, in a scenario where booking deletion is expected to happen, ID reusing feels more a bug than a feature, so your system should store a permanent counter to avoid reusing, making it less simple. Don't take me wrong, it can be done and it isn't rocket science, but it's time and energy you don't need to spend.

Your database engine surely has a native tool to generate autoincremented primary keys, with varying names and implementations (SQL Server has identity, Oracle has sequences and identity, MySQL has auto_increment...). Use that instead.

Keep internal data and user display separated. More specifically, don't use the latter to regenerate the former. Your `COMPANY20190820007` example is trivial to compose from individual fields, either in PHP:

```
$booking_number = sprintf('%s%s%03d',
    $company_code,
    $booking_date->format('Ymd'),
    $booking_id
);
```

... or in SQL:

```
-- This is MySQL dialect, other engines use their own variations
SELECT CONCAT(company_code, DATE_FORMAT(booking_date, '%Y%m%d'), LPAD(booking_id, 3, '0')) AS booking_number
FROM ...
```

You can (and probably should) save the resulting booking_number, but you cannot use it as source for further calculations. It's exactly the same case as dates: don't need to store dates in plain English in order to eventually display them to the end-user and you definitively don't want to parse English dates back to actual dates in order to do anything else beyond printing.

---

You also mention the possibility of generating long pure-digit identifiers, as Bookings.com does. There're many ways to do it and we can't know which one they use, but you may want to considering generating a numeric hash out of your auto-incremented PK via [integer obfuscation](https://github.com/jenssegers/optimus).

Answer (score -1):

you could split your database field in two parts, so you hold the prefix and the counter separately.
then, you simply select the highest counter for your desired prefix and increment that one.

if you can't change the table structure, you could alternatively order by the id descendingly and select the first. then you can extract its counter manually. keep in mind you should pad the numbers then, or you get #9 even if #10 exists.

if padding is not an option, you can direct the database to replace your prefix. that way, you can cast the remaining string to a number and let the database sort - this will cost some performance, though, so keep the amount of records low.

Comment: i don't know if your database supports the max-operation on string-datafields, you have to try/look in the documentation.

Comment: MySql handle it